# PHP5 email fetcher library

Tags: php, symfony

Does anyone know a good PHP library to fetch emails? It would be good a Symfony2 bundle but not that's not truly mandatory. Just need something well tested and mature instead of building it on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fetch](https://github.com/tedivm/Fetch) is a little library, which covers the PHP IMAP functions into a nice object orientated style. Installable via composer and ready to use.

EDIT: I build a [FetchBundle](https://github.com/abimus/FetchBundle), which enables to configure a server in `config.yml` and retrieve the connection via the service container.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that!
Did you ever use it in production?

Comment: Yes, in an autoresponder application.

Comment: @Viorel I made a little [FetchBundle](https://github.com/abimus/FetchBundle), may you test it, and give feedback?

Comment: Sure! I was going to try it. Looks like it's what i'm looking for at first glance. Thanks!